# Reverse sed's/regexes' pattern-matching priority order

Tags: sed, regex

Consider this command:

```
echo "string.with.dots" | sed 's/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/\1\n\2/'
```

(Matches into a first capturing group any character until the last `.` and into a second capturing group any character after it.)

This outputs:

```
string.with
dots
```

Reasonably (I think) I tought that using anchors in the right combination would have managed to reverse such behavior (i.e. the match would have been `string` for the first capturing group and `with.dots` for the second capturing group), but:

```
echo "string.with.dots" | sed 's/^\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/\1\n\2/'
echo "string.with.dots" | sed 's/^\(.*\)\.\(.*\)$/\1\n\2/'
echo "string.with.dots" | sed 's/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)$/\1\n\2/'
```

All output:

```
string.with
dots
```

I don't know how the pattern matching is implemented, but it seems that it always privileges the patterns closer to the start of the string rather than those closer to the end of the string (despite any present `^` or missing `$`).

How can **this behavior** be changed (i.e. not how to write an hard-coded solution to this example, but how to reverse the pattern-matching priority order into `sed` or into regexes in general), if possible?

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: @heemayl "the match would have been `string` for the first capturing group and `with.dots` for the second capturing group"

Comment: It's not a matter of anchoring - it's a matter of *greediness*, I think

Comment: @steeldriver You're right, searching for "sed not greedy" on Google I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed) but it seems like `sed` doesn't provide support for non-greedy searches

Comment: AFAIK that's correct - whereas in perl for example you could do `perl -pe 's/(.*?)\.(.*)/$1\n$2/'` instead of the default greedy `perl -pe 's/(.*)\.(.*)/$1\n$2/'`

Comment: This may be an XY-problem. Instead of fussing about with regex patterns, do you really just want to split the string using dot as a separator?

Comment: I think you should edit your question (or ask a new one) and give a more real-world example. Seems to me like there's a mismatch between the requirements given in the question and the requirements you're really after. Also, stackoverflow.com would be a more appropriate forum, since this is a programming question.

Comment: @glennjackman I'm considering this, by the way a correct answer exists already (both fitting the question and my problem), so as of now I'd refrain from deleting the question. Plus I removed the explanation because it really narrows down the scope to a single case which I can manage to arrange somehow. Mine was more of a general question, brought up by the problem I faced, which I think is well explained by the question itself and that might have a good answer simply in "You need to use a tool which can perform greedy searches."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add two `rev` and swap `\1` and `\2`:

```
echo "string.with.dots" | rev | sed 's/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/\2\n\1/' | rev
```

Output:

```
string
with.dots
```

Comment: That's a really clever solution. Upvoted. Looks like `sed` cannot perform non-greedy searches, which it's what I'm asking for, so I'll just wait a bit before marking this as the best answer.

Comment: For large files this hack is not very effective. Yes, sed cannot perform non-greedy searches. See http://superuser.com/a/890337/340330, too

Answer (score 3):

To get what you want try this:

```
sed -r 's/^([^.]*)\.(.*)/\1\n\2/'
```

Test:

```
$ echo "string.with.dots" | sed -r 's/^([^.]*)\.(.*)/\1\n\2/'
string
with.dots
```

`sed` will match greedily, so while you are using `sed 's/\(.*\)\.\(.*\)/\1\n\2/'` it will greedily match upto last `.` as the first captured group and then then the rest after the `.` as second.

In my `sed` expression, to stop `sed` from being greedy, i have to search for some alternatives. I have matched from the start to a `.` as the first group (`[^.]*`) and then whatever after the first match as the second.

Now if you want all portions around `.` in separate lines:

```
$ echo "string.with.dots" | sed -r 's/^([^.]*)\.([^.]*)\.(.*)/\1\n\2\n\3/'
string
with
dots
```

Comment: Thanks, upvoted because it's a good answer but the question is more about how to reverse the pattern matching order, because in case of a more complex pattern I should exclude the whole "separation" pattern from the first capturing group, I think this is ok for a `.` but I think it would be a little silly for more complex patterns, I think there could be a better solution.

Comment: @kos: `sed` will always behave greedily and there is nothing like reverse matching in `sed` AFAIK..it would be better if you provide some example of complex patterns and expected outputs ..

Comment: Yes, I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103149/non-greedy-regex-matching-in-sed) which also states the same, and [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13982225/4316166) of the top answers also suggests to exclude the "separation" pattern one or multiple times, the problem comes up when you don't know how many occurences of the "separation" pattern you will encounter, which , in general, is a very common case in regexes

Comment: @kos: Actually you can't have a generic pattern in `sed` or regex as what may seem an easy way to solve in one example might not be in another, there might be some  easier way based on the pattern..it mostly depends on the pattern you want to match....

Comment: The technique shown is the best way to get non-greedy behaviour using a tool without non-greedy quantifiers.

Comment: I agree with that, let's say I'd be happy with a regex to match any occurence of a pattern but the last without knowing how many times the pattern would occurr (or match only the last one, it's the same)

Comment: @glennjackman Probably yes, but how would someone deal with an undefinite number of occurences?

Comment: By *not* using regular expressions? By using a more flexible programming language (awk or perl or python or ...)? What is your real goal?

Comment: @glennjackman Sure, I just wanted to know if such thing it's feasible just by using `sed` in `bash`, if not I'll move towards other solutions. See my other response on your comment for an explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you can get away with using bash [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

```
$ s="string.with.dots"
$ echo "${s%%.*}"; echo "${s#*.}"
string
with.dots
$ echo "${s%.*}"; echo "${s##*.}"
string.with
dots
```

Comment: If this can match across any pattern, probably yes. Can't look into this now, but I'll check soon tomorrow. Thanks for now.

Comment: This is shell glob patterns, not regexes, but they are fairly comprehensive

Comment: Upvoted since like heeymal's answer this provides a good solution to the specific problem I posted as an example, even tough my question is more general and mostly related to `sed` and regexes in general